Identifying elements of $H^{-1}$
Let $U$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n \geq 3$.


Let $f \in H^{-1}(U) \cap L^2(U)$.


I think the action of $f$ on $g \in H_0^1(U)$ must be $$\big<f,g\big>=\int_U fg$$
Indeed $f$ is linear and $$\Big|\big<f,g\big>\Big|\leq ||f||_{L^2}||g||_{L^{2}} \leq ||f||_{L^2}||g||_{H_0^1}$$


Let $f \in H^{-1}(U) \cap L^1(U)$.


For $g \in L^{\infty}(U)\cap H_0^1(U)$, a dense subset of $H_0^1(U)$, the same action does not work, for if, $$\big<f,g\big>=\int_U fg$$ by Holder's we only get
$$\Big|\big<f,g\big>\Big|\leq ||f||_{L^1}||g||_{L^{\infty}} $$ and we can't claim $f \in H^{-1}(U).$
Is there a way to define the action of $f \in H^{-1}(U) \cap L^1(U)$ on $H_0^1(U)$ or a dense subset of it?

What does $f\in H^{-1}(U) \cap L^p(U)$ mean (regardless of $p$) ? Strictly speaking, this intersection makes no sense, as $H^{-1}(U)$ is a space of functionals, whereas $L^1(U)$ is a space of functions.
One could define that $f\in H^{-1}(U) \cap L^p(U)$
if there is $g\in L^p(U)$ such that
$$
f(v) = \int_U g \cdot v \ dx \quad \forall v\in H^1_0(U) \cap L^{p'}(U).
$$
Now for $p=2$, we have $H^1_0(U) \cap L^{p'}(U) = H^1_0(U)$, so that your thoughts about this case follow naturally.
For $p=1$ nothing more can be said: the functional $f$ acts on functions from $H^1_0(U) \cap L^\infty(U)$ by integration against $g$. Nothing can be said how $f$ acts on unbounded functions.
Although  $H^1_0(U) \cap L^\infty(U)$ is dense in $H^1_0(U)$.

Imho the main point here is: when thinking about these spaces make the distinction between functions and functionals/elements in dual space of function spaces.

In the defintion of $H^{-1}$, Evans notes that $L^2 \subset H^{-1}$, so I think it's fine to consider this type of intersection. But, yes, I agree there is a slight abuse of notation here.

More importantly, for $p=1$, must the functional $f$ act on the function $g$ from $H_0^1(U)\cap L^{\infty}(U)$ as integration against $g$?

That depends on how you define $f\in H^{-1} \cap L^1$ in the first place. If you start from the inequality $ \langle f,g\rangle \le c |g|_{L^\infty}$ for all $g\in H^1_0 \cap L^\infty$ then the answer will be different (and I do not know that answer).
